# Multibinding between 2 usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

I have 2 usercontrols. 
Usercontrol 1: The menubar which has buttons like Add, Edit, Delete, Save and Undo.
Usercontrol 2: Is a screen where the user can input text in textboxes and passwordboxes

But when I want to save I'm used to do the following when I only have 1 usercontrol which has the buttons and everything instead of the menubar and the detailscreen seperated:

```
     <Button Style="{DynamicResource SaveButton}" Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource pwConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="txtPassword" />
                        <Binding ElementName="txtRepeatPassword" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
```

But now the elementname "txtPassword" and "txtRepeatPassword" don't exist in that scope.
This is my SaveCommand when I click the save button. It receives those 2 parameters so I can check is the 2 passwords are the same and stuff like that.

```
    private void SaveUserExecute(object passwords)
    {
        try
        {
            var passwordvalues       = (object[])passwords;
            PasswordBox passwordBox1 = (PasswordBox)passwordvalues[0];
            PasswordBox passwordBox2 = (PasswordBox)passwordvalues[1];
       ...
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you send the whole usercontrol 2 as the parameter and alter your converter to pull the password boxes out of it?

Comment: I didn't know how to do it like you said in my implementation. But I provided an answer myself which works good for me. thanks anyway!

Comment: it's kind of similar to your answer and a bit of a hack as well.  I always dread working with password boxes in WPF since you cannot bind them to anything and require these round-about hacks to wire things up.

Answer (score 0):

Because my 2 usercontrols shared the same DataContext I've made 2 properties which represent my PasswordBoxes. When I initialize that view I did the following:

```
    public InputUserView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = InputUserViewModel.Instance;
        InputUserViewModel.Instance.PasswordBox1 = txtPassword;
        InputUserViewModel.Instance.PasswordBox2 = txtRepeatPassword;
    }
```

So now my viewmodel has knowledge of those 2 passwordboxes. I think It's not really that good, but it works for me and I can live with it

Answer (score 0):

This is easy if you use the MVVM pattern. You can have one ViewModel which can be the DataContext to each of your user controls, and your main Window. Then just bind to the properties on each of these.

Below is an example of a ViewModel, it has fields exposed by properties which we can bind to:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Command _command;

    public Command Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _command = new Command(this);
    }

    private string _textBoxOnUserControlOne;
    private string _textBoxOnUserControlTwo;

    public string TextBoxOnUserControlOne
    {
        get { return _textBoxOnUserControlOne; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _textBoxOnUserControlOne) return;
            _textBoxOnUserControlOne = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxOnUserControlOne");
        }
    }

    public string TextBoxOnUserControlTwo
    {
        get { return _textBoxOnUserControlTwo; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _textBoxOnUserControlTwo) return;
            _textBoxOnUserControlTwo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxOnUserControlTwo");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Here is the command class, where I am going to work with both of these properties:

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    private readonly ViewModel _viewModel;

    public Command(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var dataOnControlOne = _viewModel.TextBoxOnUserControlOne;
        var dataOnControlTwo = _viewModel.TextBoxOnUserControlTwo;

        //Use these values
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Now, here is my first user control 1 which is bound to one of the fields on my ViewModel, notice the DataContext:

```
<UserControl ... DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding TextBoxOnUserControlOne}" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is a second UserControl with the same DataContext, and the textbox is bound to a different property:

```
<UserControl ... DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding TextBoxOnUserControlTwo}" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my main window, which contains both of these user controls, and a button bound to my command class:

```
<Window ... DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <my:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,69,0,0" x:Name="userControl11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" Width="155" />
        <my:UserControl2 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="160,132,0,0" x:Name="userControl12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="48" Width="158" />
        <Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding Command}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="199,198,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And finally my App.Xaml class, to glue everything together:

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
         <wpfApplication4:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here, we have seperate user controls, and the fields are bound to properties on the one view model. This viewmodel passes itself into the command class, which can then access the properties which the textboxes on the seperate usercontrols are bound to, and work with them when the button is pressed. I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I'm aware of your implementation. It's easy with just textboxes but in my case there are also passwordboxes. And I can't bind the Password from a passwordbox to a property like you do the Text from a textbox... But I didn't mentioned it very well that the problem is specially for the passwordboxes. My bad, sorry